# Docker Client - standalone (portable) version on Windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows, docker

Does Docker support the standalone (version, xcopy installer) version?

I would like to use docker only to create Windows container images (not run containers) in .NET C# code, and I cannot assume that the machine on which code would be run has docker preinstalled, so having portable version bundled with the code would help.

OS: Windows Server

**Edit 2: Docker Client is needed only**

Comment: What do you expect to do with a "standalone" version? Container functionality is provided by the OS, not just Docker, whether it's Windows Containers or Linux through WSL. You won't be able to use containers on a machine without explicitly enabling the relevant OS features

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I would like to use standalone version only to create image and export it as a .tar (won't start containers on that machine).

Answer (score 2):

Try this link:

https://download.docker.com/win/static/stable/x86_64/

(((((( for 30 chars

Answer (score -2):

Windows requires an emulator to run Linux in order to create a Linux container.

To make it portable, use "Portable-VirtualBox" (administrator privileges required) or "Qemu" (slowly) to run the Linux environment.

I don't think the Windows container creation environment can be made portable.

Comment: Just to make it clean, I would like to use ONLY docker client (literally build image, and save it as a tar - nothing else), and everything is Windows based creating Win Container Images.

Comment: `Windows requires an emulator to run Linux in order to create a Linux container` no it doesn't. That's what WSL is for. Windows also includes a hypervisor (for quite some time) for those cases where an actual VM is needed, that's quite a bit faster than either VirtualBox or QEmu

Comment: WSL2 is running Linux on the emulator. Also, it is not portable.

Comment: No it's not. WSL2 isn't emulating Linux, it's a full Linux distro. And *emulator* is something **completely** different from a VM hypervisor. A VM running Linux doesn't "emulate" Linux

Comment: You can't create a container with the Docker client alone.

Comment: Yes, because that functionality is provided by Windows. In recent versions, through WSL2. In previous versions, through a Hyper-V VM. Not any kind of emulator